# insert the figure to HTML file in C++

Tags: c++

I have used VS2017 in windows 7 to build a C++ program. I want to insert a figure(D:\Figure\figure.bmp)  to a HTML file generated at run time(the bmp file is in the same folder as the exe).  But I failed.

I tried StreamWriter, But I failed.

```cpp
    CStdioFile htmlFile;
    html_name = "reports_pass/" + reportInfo.m_bt_addr + ".html";
    if(htmlFile.Open(html_name,CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite))
    {       
            CString strHTML =  "<html>";
            strHTML += "<title>Title</title>";
            strHTML += "<body>";
            strHTML += "<h1 align=center>main </h1>";
            strHTML += "<img src = 'D:\\Figure\\figure.bmp' />";

                     strHTML += "</html>";
            strHTML += "<\body>";
        htmlFile.WriteString(strHTML);
        htmlFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: When you say "doc file", I assume you mean Microsoft Word. You'll need a library for writing that format. We don't recommend software libraries on StackOverflow, but we will help you if you have problems using the one you choose. Find one, read its documentation, and if you still get stuck, come back and ask a specific question about using it.

Comment: Sorry, HTML file.

Comment: You already asked this question and accepted the answer. Here you are missing the `</body>` tag and the file name is the wrong format. It should be `file:///D://figure//figure.bmp`. Some older web browsers may not recognize .bmp format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand HTML format firstly. Write the text to the correct position in html file as below:

```
 <img src = "figure.bmp_relative_path_to_the_html_file" />
```

Then, once you open the html in web browser, you will find the image is shown properly.

Comment: How to add it in my case？

Comment: strHTML += "<img src = 'D:\\Figure\\figure.bmp' />";   Is that OK?

Comment: It depends where the figure.bmp shows in the html file , maybe you want to show in the beginning of the file , or show in the bottom of the file , or anywhere .  You may try several times to find the current  position .

Comment: For example: the html code will show your figure.bmp under the "balabala" text in the html file <html>
<head>
<title>demo a figure shown in a html file</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>balabala</h1>
<img src = 'D:\\Figure\\figure.bmp' />
</body>
</html>

Comment: I have tried strHTML += "<img src = 'D:\\Figure\\figure.bmp' />"; but no figure showed.

Comment: You should not append the <...> to the end of strHTML, instead  you should insert the <...> to the proper position .

Comment: Could you please show me the corrected code? I do not understand your meaning

Comment: </title> </head> <body> <h1>balabala</h1> <img src = 'D:\\Figure\\figure.bmp' /> </body> </html>

Comment: You firstly should find the correct position in the strHTML, and then insert <img src = 'D:\\Figure\\figure.bmp' /> , that is OK